# Python requests xpath web

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm still a beginner and I'm trying to extract location from a profil linkedin using requests, here is my code and also i've decoded page.content (you'll find it in the output). I didn't find my xpath in the html code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/peter-zorich-9567a610/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
location = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[1]')
print(location)
x = page.content.decode("utf-8")
print(x)
file = open(r'C:\Users\Hamza\Desktop\file_text.txt', 'w')
file.write(x)
```

**Output:**
[]

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.
  var trk = "bf";
  var trkInfo = "bf";
  var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
    if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trk = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
    else if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkInfo=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
      trkInfo = cookies[i].substring(8);
    }
  }

  if (window.location.protocol == "http:") {
    // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
      if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {
        window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  // Get the new domain. For international domains such as
  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com
  var domain = "www.linkedin.com";
  if (domain != location.host) {
    var subdomainIndex = location.host.indexOf(".linkedin");
    if (subdomainIndex != -1) {
      domain = "www" + location.host.substring(subdomainIndex);
    }
  }

  window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/authwall?trk=" + trk + "&trkInfo=" + trkInfo +
      "&originalReferer=" + document.referrer.substr(0, 200) +
      "&sessionRedirect=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
}
</script>
</head></html>
```

Comment: How have you tried to debug this issue? Are you certain your request is resulting in the content you think it is (have you inspected `page.content`)? If you shorten your `xpath` expression, does it return the appropriate container for your target content?

Comment: @larsks how can i inspecte page.content? here's the output when i print(tree)  : 
 <Element html at 0x20c1958>

Comment: `page.context` is just a Python string. You could write it to a file and then open the file in your favorite text editor.

Comment: @larsks when i try to save, error : write() argument must be str, not HtmlElement . Should i convert it ? How can i save the htmlElement to inspect it

Comment: #lines_i_added_to_save

-> file = open(r'C:\Users\Hamza\Desktop\file_text.txt', 'w')

-> file.write(tree)

Comment: I keep talking about `page.content`, which is a string, and for some reason you keep trying to inspect or write your `tree` variable. That's not what I suggested.

Comment: @larsks i'm sorry i'm still beginner to python, i just got what you meant. Now i've html outputed in a file. i didn't find my xpath there. i'll edit post and share the html code

Comment: @larsks by the way : print(page.status_code) = 999